# Uploading video files in the mysql database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This code can upload video files but only to my specific folder. How can I upload the video files into my database and retrieve it for viewing/streaming. Could you help me please? I have read something about just not uploading it to the database but uploading it to the server? What does that means?

This is my view:

```
           <body>
    <div id="container">

        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div id="body">


           <div id="div2">
          <div id="upload">
        <form class="cssform" name="property" id="property" method="POST" action="<?php echo    base_url()?>main/add_video"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
       <table>
      <tr>

        <td><input type="file" id="video" name="video" ></td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
           <td> <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
      </form>
       </div>


            <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/logout" ?>'>Logout</a>
        </div>
        <div id ="searchBox">

</div>
</div>
        <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my controller:

```
       public function add_video(){

    if (isset($_FILES['video']['name']) && $_FILES['video']['name'] != '') {
        unset($config);
        $date = date("ymd");
        $configVideo['upload_path'] = './videos';
        $configVideo['max_size'] = '10240';
        $configVideo['allowed_types'] = 'avi|flv|wmv|mp3';
        $configVideo['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $configVideo['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $video_name = $date.$_FILES['video']['name'];
        $configVideo['file_name'] = $video_name;

        $this->load->library('upload', $configVideo);
        $this->upload->initialize($configVideo);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('video')) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
            $videoDetails = $this->upload->data();
            echo "Successfully Uploaded";
               }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Why not file system for video hosting ?

Comment: I mean to say why are you using database to store videos. Store files in server and save file names in db.

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT want to upload to the database...that would become an enormous amount of data to be unnecessarily managed by MySQL, not to mention a huge development undertaking to view the videos.

You could change your code to determine what folder it should be uploaded to, and move it there after the upload to `.videos\` is complete.  Perhaps by username, or date or similar, and have a table in your database that stores the folder name of where the file is located and other video related information.

At that point, you can use MySQL to locate the files, and other info you've stored, and use that to create a valid link to view the video, which would be in the folder that it was moved to.

Comment: do you mean that I need to store only the link of the video to the database? How can I locate the files using mySQL?

Comment: check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWFVuW0b79nLbW25P340j1dT

Comment: the video you recommended just shows how to upload the video into the server. I would like to know how to retrieve the video and play it into my website. 

I tried following the video and integrated the codes into my own but I am currently facing a problem. I have used the uniqid to produce a random number. When I echo the file name there's no problem, but when I check the uploaded file in the folder it adds the key UNDERSCORE after the file name. For example I echo the file name and it outputs filename.flv but when I check the file it's filenameUNDERSCORE.flv

Comment: I've added this code into my controller  
$file_ext = explode('.', $video_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
            
          
            
            $file_new_name = uniqid('', true).'.'. $file_ext;
            
            $file_destination = 'videos/'.$file_new_name;
            
            $configVideo['file_name'] = $file_new_name;

Comment: I've solved the underscore problem. I just need to remove the true in uniquid('', true);